# Как определить какой версии IP адрес в строке IPv4 или IPv6?

Tags: c++, строки, ip

Как можно проще всего и самое главное эффективнее всего узнать какая версия IP адреса в строке IPv4 или IPv6? Может можно использовать, что-то более элегантное помимо регулярных выражений?

Comment: Точки или двоеточия, длина...

Comment: А как вы собираетесь трактовать ситуацию когда в формате IPv6 указан адрес IPv4?